# 'sep' in 'read.csv' doesn't seem to work?

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a csv file that looks like this (see below first few lines of the data) and I've used this line to import it,

```
read.csv2('hospital_finance_2008.csv', sep=';', check.names = F)
```

But it all came in one column only. Also how to get rid of the quotations when the first variable doesn't have them?

**Content of .csv:**

Estabelecimento - CNES;"Privado com fins lucrativos  clientela mista";"Privado com fins lucrativos   clientela privada";"Privado sem fins lucrativos     clientela mista";"Privado sem fins lucrativos   clientela privada";"Público     clientela fechada";"Público     clientela mista";"Público   clientela SUS";"Total"
0000027 CASA DE SAUDE SANTA HELENA;"1";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1"
0000035 HOSPITAL MENDO SAMPAIO;"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1";"1"
0000094 MATERNIDADE PADRE GERALDO LEITE BASTOS;"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1";"1"
0000183 HOSPITAL SAMARITANO;"0";"1";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1"
0000221 HOSPITAL SAO SEBASTIAO;"0";"1";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1"
0000396 HOSPITAL DAS CLINICAS;"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1";"1"
0000418 HOSPITAL AGAMENON MAGALHAES;"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1";"1"
0000426 HOSPITAL OTAVIO DE FREITAS;"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1";"1"
0000434 IMIP;"0";"0";"1";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1"
0000477 HOSPITAL OSWALDO CRUZ;"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1";"1"
0000485 FUNDACAO ALTINO VENTURA;"0";"0";"1";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1"

Comment: You code actually works fine for me, I get a 10x17 data frame (copy pasted your .csv content). BTW, it's not wise to use `check.names=FALSE`, you should rather work with valid column names.

Comment: How did you encode the file? In your comment, there seems to be a linebreak missing before `0000027`. Is this in your file as well?
Using your file and your code, this works fine for me.

Comment: @pandayo Yes there's a line break. Let me try again. Is there anyway I can upload the original csv file?

Comment: I got an error message "> read.csv2('hospitals/finance/hospital_finance_2008.csv',sep=';')
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string 1"

Comment: @LLT I spotted sth, please see my answer below. Do you still get the error using that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a line break missing in first line of .csv. You could use `readLines` and `gsub` the linebreak into first line. Also there are weird quotes, you could set them to nothing using `quote=''` and delete them using `gsub` thereafter. Finally delete the commas in last column.

```
rl <- readLines('~/Downloads/hospital_finance_2008.csv')
rl[1] <- gsub('0000027', '\n0000027', rl[1])
dat <- read.csv2(text=rl, sep=';', quote='')
dat[] <- lapply(dat, gsub, pat='"', rep='')
dat <- type.convert(dat, as.is=TRUE)  ## convert to numeric
dat[[length(dat)]] <- as.numeric(gsub(',', '', dat[[length(dat)]]))
head(dat)
#                         X.Estabelecimento...CNES X..Privado.com.fins.lucrativos....clientela.mista..
# 1             0000027 CASA DE SAUDE SANTA HELENA                                                   1
# 2                 0000035 HOSPITAL MENDO SAMPAIO                                                   0
# 3 0000094 MATERNIDADE PADRE GERALDO LEITE BASTOS                                                   0
# 4                    0000183 HOSPITAL SAMARITANO                                                   0
# 5                 0000221 HOSPITAL SAO SEBASTIAO                                                   0
# 6                  0000396 HOSPITAL DAS CLINICAS                                                   0
#   X..Privado.com.fins.lucrativos....clientela.privada.. X..Privado.sem.fins.lucrativos....clientela.mista..
# 1                                                     0                                                   0
# 2                                                     0                                                   0
# 3                                                     0                                                   0
# 4                                                     1                                                   0
# 5                                                     1                                                   0
# 6                                                     0                                                   0
#   X..Privado.sem.fins.lucrativos....clientela.privada.. X..P.fa.blico....clientela.fechada.. X..P.fa.blico....clientela.mista..
# 1                                                     0                                    0                                  0
# 2                                                     0                                    0                                  0
# 3                                                     0                                    0                                  0
# 4                                                     0                                    0                                  0
# 5                                                     0                                    0                                  0
# 6                                                     0                                    0                                  0
#   X..P.fa.blico....clientela.SUS.. X..Total...
# 1                                0           1
# 2                                1           1
# 3                                1           1
# 4                                0           1
# 5                                0           1
# 6                                1           1
```

Comment: Thank you but still doesn't work. I've uploaded the dataset to https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/hospital_finance_2008_csv/21195490 . Forgot to mention. The codes I used used to work before I used the later version of R.

Comment: @LLT I see, please see update.